# Selenium click to expand menu and not click on href behind it

Tags: selenium

There is a menu I am trying to click without triggering its "href":

```
<a class=" mnav mnavt2 uif_link" href="/xxx/xxx/abc">Menu</a>`
```

Below is my Selenium code:

```
click("//a[text()='Menu']")
```

What happened was it clicks on the Menu and triggered the "href". How do I avoid doing that?

I tried clickMouse and it just doesn't expand the menu.

Comment: Is the parent tag of the anchor tag clickable? You can try to click on the parent.

Comment: Can you `click on the Menu and be on the same page` _Manually_?

Comment: Which language are you using?

Comment: This would be a very strange web page if you click on a link and don't expect the page to follow the link.  Why do you want to avoid following the href...what are you really trying to accomplish?

Comment: @Frank using the parent tag works but would make the script break later on when they change the href to another page. For example, I wanted it to click Menu > Clothings > Top. The current parent tag only says `<div class="primaryLink">` or `<div class="secondaryLinl">`.

Comment: @DebanjanB Yes, the Menu expand on the same page manually.

Comment: @RatmirAsanov I am doing Selenium scripting in CatchPoint.

Comment: @BreaksSoftware So it's a menu that is supposed to expand until the last options before it should go to a specific href. I just find it strange they embedded the hrefs in the submenus before it reaches the last. Cause manually, when I click on the submenus before the last one, it doesn't go to the hrefs.

Comment: @JoeySaw Check out my Answer and let me know the status.

Answer (score 0):

we can use "Mouse- Right click". It would click on that element without trigger href. Please use below line and let me know if you need further help.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("your xpath goes here")).sendKeys(Keys.RIGHT);
```

Comment: This is in CatchPoint so I think I need to do a runScript() syntax for the above. But I am lacking in that skill. How do I code it to work in the Console in Chrome? I remember the CP folks used document.getElementsByID('xpath') but not quite sure if sendKeys work. I tried and got Uncaught ReferenceError saying Keys is not defined. `document.getElementsByClassName('mNav mNavt1 uif_link').sendKeys(Keys.RIGHT);` By the way, I didn't want to use the xpath because it has a lot of tags on it so I decide the class would be better as it's less likely to change when they do web development (I hope).

Answer (score 0):

If there's some Hover Over functionality implemented on this 'Menu' Link then use this method:

```
WebElement element=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(@href,'/xxx/xxx/abc')]"));

    String mouseOver = "var evObj = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');" +
                        "evObj.initMouseEvent(\"mouseover\",true, false, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);" +
                        "arguments[0].dispatchEvent(evObj);";

((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript(mouseOver, element);
```

If there's no Hover Over Functionality, there should be some arrow button or something that expands the Menu without triggering the Menu Link. For this I will need the HTML around the Menu Link and also a Screenshot of the Menu.

Comment: Yes, as per suggestion from Frank, using the parent tag works, only problem in future would be if they swap the menu or submenu items around. But so far, I think this is the only way that is hassle free.

Answer (score 0):

As per your question I assume the following :

- There is a *Menu* item which contains a `href` attribute and is clickable.
- The *Menu* item also contains *Sub Menu* items which you need to expand.

Your actual *usecase* is probhably to *MOUSE HOVER* the *Menu* item and expand the *Sub Menu* items.

To achieve that you can adopt the following approach :

- Use *Actions* class to *Mouse Hover* as follows :

  - *Java approach* :

    ```
    import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;

    Actions act = new Actions(driver);
    //Use any one from the following 3 Locator Strategies
    WebElement elem = driver.findElement(By.linkText("Menu"))
    //WebElement elem = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a.mnav.mnavt2.uif_link[href='/xxx/xxx/abc']"))
    //WebElement elem = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@class='mnav mnavt2 uif_link' and @href='/xxx/xxx/abc']"))
    act.moveToElement(elem).perform();
    ```

Comment: Because I am scripting in CatchPoint and it has its own simplified Selenium scripting, I am not able to perform your suggestion above. I may have to do a runScript() syntax and try to translate your driver suggestion (which I do not know how).

Answer (score 0):

So guys, I used Frank's suggestion.